Why did my credit score drop when I paid off a car loan early?
Ok, so, I have a pretty good credit score, I worked the last 3yrs building it. My question is, I just paid off my first car loan about 2yrs early. I now have 2 cc's that I've had over 2 yrs and a new car loan on my credit. But my credit scores dropped over 40 points. I don't understand, why did it drop and will it go back up? I'm so confused and worked so hard. Please someone help explain this. I'm freaking out.

Don't freak out - credit score does not affect your life as much as credit card companies want you to believe.

is the "new car loan" truly a new loan or the same one that you paid of early?

why do you care what your score is?

Credit score works differently in different places around the world and this is an international site. Please edit, tag or comment to indicate where you are.

It may be as simple as that paying off the loan reduced your cash on hand, and therefore briefly reduced your ability to pay other loans. I fairly regularly see swings of 20 points without doing anything significant. Most of the time, unless you are actively looking for a loan or your credit rating is marginal, a bit of bouncing around is expected and harmless.


I don't understand, why did it drop and will it go back up?

Yes it will go back up; if you keep paying off your credit cards each month, and you make payments on any other loans you have.
Why did it go down? You paid off a loan. You applied for a new loan. Therefore items that are used in the calculation changed.
Because these numbers don't change in an instant it is possible that in the short term it could go down even more, or next month it would be close to the value you used to have.
Timing of these scores aren't in sync. The lenders don't report their numbers but once per month, and not all lenders report on the same day. The credit card company that provides a score number to their customers only pulls the updated score once a month.
That means it is possible that the history shows you currently have zero, one, or two car loans.
To know what is impacting the score, look to the source of the score. I have always gotten a short list of things that are impacting my score.

Credit score is an indicator of how well you make monthly debt payments, and how "trusted" you can be to continue to make payments. It's a combination of your past behavior and some of your current financial situation. I say "some" because things like income are not considered in your credit score, but are definitely considered in your ability to actually get a loan.
Changes to your credit profile, like adding a new account, paying off a loan, etc. can temporarily change your credit score, but in the long run your payment history is more important.
Don't freak out - credit score does not affect your life as much as credit card companies want you to believe. Just make your payments on time, don't overuse debt, and you'll be fine.

+1 -- Credit score basically only impacts interest rates on car loans and home mortgages. So unless OP is actively shopping for one of those they can basically ignore their credit score.

Well it can also affect how much deposit you have to pay for utilities, etc., but the fantasy that you see in credit score commercials where you can suddenly buy more stuff because your score went from 640 to 720 is ridiculous.

There are 6 major factors that determine your credit score. Let's look at each one.

Late payments (large impact). That shouldn't have been affected by a new loan.

Credit card usage ratio (large impact). Again, that's independent of a car loan, unless you charged a down payment to one. You may want to consider if this did change e.g. due to holiday spending.

Derogatory marks (bankruptcies, charge offs, large impact). Not a factor, particularly if somebody gave you a new loan.

Average account age (medium impact). This hit you because you have a new account, lowering the average age, particularly if you have few accounts on your record and they weren't that old.

Total accounts (medium impact). This actually improved because you added an account. Your closed car loan will stay on your record for 10 years, helping you here.

Hard inquiries (low impact). The credit pulls for your new car loan hit you here. If you shopped around, there's a time window where multiple pulls only count as one, and the length varies by specific algorithm, somewhere from 14-45 days.


So your score took a medium hit due to age, a medium gain due to account number, and a small hit due to the hard pull. As time goes on, average account age will rise, and the hard pulls will drop off after 2 years, so your score will go back up.

It is possible that paying off a car loan early can result in a slight blip in your credit score, although you have cleared the entire amount. Sometimes when your loan company does report to the credit bureaus that the loan has been repaid, it may take some time before this is properly reflected. I am not 100% sure but that could be the case as well.

Ok so I see two very clear reasons why your Credit Score dropped by 40 points.
1. First and foremost, it's great to want to pay off a loan early to obtain a new loan, but if you just paid off a car loan or any loan early you will see a dip in your Credit score. The reason is because paying off a car loan reduces the number of active accounts on your credit report. And having a new loan isn't showing long-term payment history. It's also more debt for you as well. I am sure the new car loan amount is more than the early payoff amount. Open accounts show that you're currently managing your credit. However, the dip is usually only temporary, and your score may rise over time as your debt-to-income ratio decreases. The amount your score drops depends on your overall financial situation.
They don't tell you that once a vehicle loan is paid off, it is not going to do anything for your credit. Making or not making the payments monthly is the only thing that affects your credit unfortunately. Once its paid off, it doesn't matter to any lender or credit reporting agency. But that's a catch 22 because if you still had the loan they would say it's a great credit score but you can not afford the new loan financially in most cases. Never understood that part of it all. But if you are making enough to afford more than one loan, then keep that car or other loan on there until after you purchase the new car or obtain a new loan then pay it off early.
2. When you try to obtain a new loan they do a credit check and it is usually a hard credit check not a soft one. Hard credit checks stay on your credit for a length of time and affect your score. They do go away but not right away.
Those two things alone are enough for 40 dip in score but don't worry, it will go back up as you make your payments and the good thing is that you already got the new loan so sit back and enjoy the new car.

Your credit score doesn’t actually reflect your ability to repay loans as it should. It is just the result of a formula that takes various facts of your life into account and calculates a score.
So I would say between two people the one who just repaid their loan is the lower risk. But that formula might count “repaid loans” as a negative. They expected 84 monthly payments but you paid only 43. It might count regular monthly repayments which have gone down (negative). The formula may prefer unchanging payments (yours just went down, negative). In other words, the formula might take lots of things into account in strange and nonsensical ways and reduce your credit worthiness when a reasonable view would increase it.

Paying off all your consumer debt is the best thing you can do for your credit score.  If you carry a balance on your credit cards get them to zero ASAP.  Don't fret the credit score, it will take care of itself.

Credit card utilization is a major factor, but other forms of consumer debt namely car loans, student loans and mortgages are not. They affect your debt-to-income, which is going to affect whether you can get new loans, but that that isn't reflected in your credit score.

Quibble: Paying off all your consumer debt is the best thing to do, but not necessarily the best thing for your credit score. As long as you make payments on time and keep your utilization low enough, having debt has a pretty neutral impact on your score.

First of all, I'd like to apologise on behalf of the troglodytic responses you've received thus far. I understand you're freaking out and I would like to encourage you to take a moment to breathe and we'll look at this
I'm going to assume the following:

You live in North America where credit scores and credit culture are valid concerns
You are writing this post in good faith with the intention of learning how this might have happened
You value your credit score because you hope one day to leverage it for something like a mortgage.

It is somewhat normal, when taking out a loan for there to be a dip in your credit score. However, 40 points is quite excessive. Are you using the same credit score ranking company for both the before and after?
My first point of contact would be to reach out directly to the credit score company and ask if they can shed any light on it.
40 points is quite a big drop and without having your credit history in front of me it's quite hard to pinpoint exactly where something might have happened. That's why I would strongly recommend contacting a credit score service as they should be able to help you get to the bottom of it.
I wish you the best on this.

I have 2 small credit cards that I only use 9% of every month and pay them off monthly. I paid off my first car loan and bought a new car acquiring a new loan. I am up to date with all my accounts and have no negative marks. I do love in North America and I do Want to buy a house in 2026 you're absolutely right. My score was a 792 when I paid off the first car loan, and the new loan was already being reported. Then this month the loan showed as paid off/ closed and now my score is 744. I feel so defeated because I've worked so hard to bring my credit up that much.
